# System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_MetadataToken()' cannot be used on the current platform

Tags: .net, xamarin, windows-10-universal, portable-class-library

Here's the exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Additional information: The API 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_MetadataToken()' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information.

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
```

### My setup

I have a PCL project (Profile7) that is used for common Xamarin forms code. The PCL is referenced by Android, iOS and UWP projects in the same solution. The PCL references a 3rd party library where the exception is thrown from (IdentityModel.OidcClient Nuget package). The Android project runs as expected. The UWP project throws the exception. The exception occurs because the dynamic keyword is used in the logging code in IdentityModel.OidcClient. I've created an issue on the author's Github site as well (https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/issues/43).

Interestingly enough the author has a sample UWP application that directly references IdentityModel.OidcClient (no PCL), and it runs fine. It seems the difference between the author's app and mine is the use of a PCL.

I've tried changing the target profile to 111, but to no avail. How can I fix this?

**Update**

IdentityModel.OidcClient PCL project uses profile 259. I set my PCL project to profile 259, but the exception still occurs.

Comment: A PCL uses a limited subset of .NET based on the profile used. Only those parts of .NET that are included in all of the platforms targeted by the PCL will be available in the PCL. IOW if Xamarin.Android supports API "XYZ" but UWP does not then API "XYZ" will not be available in the PCL. So my assumption would then be that the library is using an API that is not available in your PCL due to the target platforms of the PCL.

Comment: Any chance you can ditch PCL by putting your common Xamarin.Forms code into a shared project and then referencing that shared project (and platform-specific `IdentityModel.OidcClient` implementations) from your platform-specific projects?

Comment: @Kirill Shlenskiy, unfortunately that's not an option at this point.

Comment: Upgrading Xamarin did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Xamarin for Visual Studio to 4.2.719 resolved the issue. It was either that or the reboot. :)